# How can add multiple images to a uitableviewcell programatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can add multiple images to a uitableviewcell programatically.

The case is first cell may contain two images, second may contain 1 ,2 ,3, or 4. etc.. maximum number of images in a tableviewcell is 5.

My code is

In ViewDidLoad

```
imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 300)];
imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 140)];
imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 260, 300, 140)];
imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 150, 140)];
imageView5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 260, 150, 140)];
imageView6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 150, 140)];
imageView7 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 100, 150, 140)];


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell   *image_cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (image_cell==nil)
    {
        image_cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

        if (sub_image_array.count==1)
            {
            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
            }

        else if (sub_image_array.count==2)
        {
            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];

            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView3];

        }
        else if (sub_image_array.count==3)
        {
           [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
           [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView4];
            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView5];

        }
        else if (sub_image_array.count==4)
        {
            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView6];
            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView7];
            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView4];
            [image_cell.contentView addSubview:imageView5];

        }
    return image_cell;
}
```

Comment: did you implement `CellForRowAtIndex` method and tried adding multiple imageViews in it?

Comment: yes, i implemented CellForRowAtIndex

Comment: then where is the problem? you can add as many imageViews in it as you want?

Comment: How you want to show images, Vertical or Horizontal? You need to create subclass `UITableViewCell` and create a custom cell. Add images in that also you need to manage cell height if you want image to be show in vertical layout.

Comment: my problem is images are changing when scrolling the tableview

Comment: I've edited my question. please check the code

Comment: You should not keep the imageview in the viewcontroller that is returning the table view cells but the a subclass of a `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

There several key issues with your code.

1. Cells get reused. You keep adding image views over and over to each cell as it is used. Before reusing a cell you need to remove and existing image views that may have been added earlier.
2. Views can only have one parent view. You can't preallocate a fixed set of image views and then attempt to add each one to multiple cells. Get rid of your seven prebuilt image views. Instead, create the images views as needed for each cell.

The best approach is to create your own custom table view cell class that is passed an image array. Then the cell takes care of setting up its own images views as needed. This puts all of the logic in the cell class where it belongs instead of the putting that nasty logic in the view controller.